# Conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY in One to One Relationship Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

While I am going to add-migration it's ok but while I am going to run update-database I am getting this type of error in package manager console

The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.ServiceTypes_dbo.Services_ServiceTypeID". The conflict occurred in database "Otaidea", table "dbo.Services", column 'ServicesID'.

My two model:

```
public class Services
{
    [Key]
    public int ServicesID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Register Date")]
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

    public int ServiceTypeID { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

}
```

my another Table:

```
public class ServiceType
{
    [ForeignKey("Services")]
    public int ServiceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public virtual Services Services { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The ForeignKey("Services") must go in the Services Entity, above the ServiceTypeID  property

Comment: i don't understand what you want to say  please can you explain i am new bie

Comment: Services has ServiceType. correct? So, you don't need to reference Services inside ServiceType. You need to reference ServiceType inside Service, and also remove the ForeignKey from ServiceType

Comment: can you rewrite the  the two class for me because brother i am too week  in english .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relationship in your models are wrong. Services has a "Type", so the Foreign Key goes from ServiceType to Service. You don't need to reference Services inside ServiceType

You should create your model like this:

**Services**

```
public class Services
{
    [Key]
    public int ServicesID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Register Date")]
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ServiceType")]
    public int ServiceTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }    
}
```

**ServiceType**

```
public class ServiceType
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

I would also do the same with the `ApplicationUserID` property, but since you didn't post about it I let it as is.

Also, it would be better if you drop your database and let Entity Framework create it again for you. Because you had a wrong model relationship things got "messy".

Comment: thank you #jpgrassi . but  ApplicationUser class and service claass many to one relation thats mean A application user has many services ... how can define this relationshipp ??? i am using asp.net mvc identity framework ...... in this framework applicationuserID was a varchar/string  instead of int ... how can define this relation

Comment: Well my best guess without seeing much of code is that in ApplicationUser  you have a List of Services. This is another question though, you should write a new one :)

Comment: my application user class inherit from identity user how can define thats relationship

Comment: @Hoque, I'm not much of an expert on working with the ASP.Net Identity. That's why I advise you to ask another question. This is a different problem.

Comment: i am a new bie in stack overflow thats why i cant ask more then one question in a day

Comment: Check these links: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun. Also, did my answer solved your initial problem?